# Firing an event on SFTP file receipt completion with Paramiko SFTP server

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

If I use the Paramiko server for SFTP, is it possible to fire an event when a file is received?

I have read the reference manual and looked at some example code and cannot see any examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [`SFTPHandle.close` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_handle.SFTPHandle.close).

Though it is called, whenever any kind of work with the file is finished. Including for example a download.

If you need to filter out uploads only, you need to add more checks. Like verify that the file was originally opened with a write access. See the `flags` argument to the [`SFTPHandle` constructor](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_handle.SFTPHandle).